# Netbeans compiler bug

Tags: php, netbeans

I use Netbeans for my project but it doesn't compile my file and just shows my whatever I have typed. It can't recognize html and php file. can you guys help me for this problem .

[image: My code]

and this is my output instead of "Hello world"
[image]

Comment: There are just way too many information missing to be able to answer your question.  PHP file is just at text file.  You can execute it with php myfile.php or deployed it using a webserver such as apache with PHP support.

Comment: If you use a web hosting service, you can have netbeans automatically deploy your php files for you.  You then only need to provide the ftp server, user name and password.

Answer (score 1):

look at this project encoding, meta encoding

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer because you haven't explained to the OP what is causing the problem, nor what needs to be done to fix the problem. Just providing a screen shot is not sufficient.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: set everything as shown in the picture and write if it's ok or not